# apache tomat7 not starting in browser?

Tags: java, apache, windows-8, tomcat7

Hi i'm using Apache Tomcat 7,with jdk 1.7 in windows 8. and i have installed tomcat successfully in windows 8,now i'm going hit URL in browser like"localhost:8080" it's work fine,after i open eclipse created web-application & i configured tomcat with that web-application,now i try to restart [i'm getting error like!!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3WZRP.png)

so for that,i have stopped tomcat in services(task-manger-service).now it will work fine(it get restarted in eclipse and works fine). when i hit URL in browser like"localhost:8080" [i' getting error like !](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GT6F3.png) and more i have added java_home,Catalina_home and also path.

can any one help me out it should work in both eclipse & browser?

Comment: The first problem is that you're using the default configurations for both Apache Tomcat and Eclipse Tomcat, which defaults to port 8080. Your main options are either change the configuration for one of those to use a different port (and matching changes to your clients), or enable only one of them at a time, like what you did. The second problem sounds like you got a servlet that got a runtime exception. Hard to tell what that's about unless you post the errors from your client and/or eclipse tomcat logfile.

Answer (score 1):

First do

```
netstat -a -b -o
```

and see if ports that are configured in Eclipse Tomcat are free. If they are not free kill that process

```
taskkill /PID <pid>
```

Use /F flag if needed. You should get PID fro, netstat command. You should get Eclipse tomcat ports from Server tab of JavaEE perspective

[image]

Then start your tomcat.

PS : If you are getting 404 either you are entering incorrect URL or server is not up in the first place. In any case check the logs if you are getting 404.

Comment: yes thanks dear all finally i got solution(after i did change in port number like tomcat admin port,HTTP/1.1,AJP/1.3) Now its work fine and more over any one can help me out how to enable ssl in apache tomcat 7

Comment: Np. For configuring SSL in tomcat you can refer [this post](http://opensourceforgeeks.blogspot.in/2014/06/supporting-https-urlson-your-server.html) I had written some time back. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps

1. Right click on your eclipse project
2. Select `Refresh`
3. Click the `Run` icon

Answer (score 0):

It is not straight forward when you invoke Tomcat from within Eclipse. Please read the FAQ section at https://wiki.eclipse.org/WTP_Tomcat_FAQ

It explains how if you start Tomcat from within Eclipse, the binaries of original directories of Tomcat are used, but the web apps etc are stored separately in the Eclipse Workspace.